# Biblioteca Gson Alterando util.Date

Tags: java, json, data, junit, gson

Ao usar a biblioteca `GSON` pra manipulação de `JSON`, percebi que ao fazer os parsers a data está sendo alterada, é ínfimo, mas é o suficiente pra quebrar o meu teste unitário com `JUnit`.

Segue um código de esboço pra mostrar o comportamento estranho.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Date data = new Date();

String dataNoFormatoJSON = gson.toJson(data);
Date dataDoJSON = gson.fromJson(dataNoFormatoJSON, Date.class);

long dataTime = data.getTime();
long dataDoJSONTime = dataDoJSON.getTime();

System.out.println(data + " - " + dataTime);
System.out.println(dataDoJSON + " - " + dataDoJSONTime);
```

Saída desse código:

```
Tue Oct 17 17:02:03 GFT 2017 - 1508270523483
Tue Oct 17 17:02:03 GFT 2017 - 1508270523000
```

Primeiro o `toString()` do `Date` e depois o `date.getTime()` que é a representação dessa data em `long`.

Perceba que o `toString`, aparentemente não demonstra nenhuma alteração, já o `date.getTime`está diferente.

primeiro(antes do parse JSON) **1508270523483**

depois(depois do parse JSON) **1508270523000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao serializar para JSON, você acaba perdendo a informação dos milissegundos. Se você printar a variável `dataNoFormatoJson`, verá que ela tem uma data no formato `Oct 18, 2017 10:41:59 AM`. Ao deserializar novamente para um objeto `Date`, este virá com os milissegundos zerados.

Uma alternativa é usar um formato de data que tenha millissegundos:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    .create();
```

---

Outra alternativa é criar um `JsonSerializer` e um `JsonDeserializer` e serializar a representação em `long` da data que tem os milissegundos (ou outra representação que você queira).

```
JsonSerializer<Date> dateSerializer = new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    if(src == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
  }
};

JsonDeserializer<Date> dateDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    if(json == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return new Date(json.getAsLong());
  }
};

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, dateSerializer)
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, dateDeserializer)
    .create();
```

Comment: usei Gson mesmo e funcionou, tks!!!